# Why does ruby’s `system` not `shellescape` the first argument?

Tags: ruby, escaping, system

When referenced in a shell, directory names with parenthesis such as:

```
/tmp/(example)
```

need to be escaped like:

```
/tmp/\(example\)
```

When I reference them in a `system` call in ruby, I have to escape them or not depending on whether they are the first argument or not.

- Unescaped directory as the first argument. Failure.

  ```
  system('/tmp/(example)/script')
  #>> sh: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `example'
  #>> sh: -c: line 0: `/tmp/(example)/script'
  #=> false
  ```
- Escaped directory as the first argument. Success.

  ```
  system('/tmp/(example)/script'.shellescape)
  #=> true
  ```
- Unescaped directory as the second argument. Success.

  ```
  system('touch', '/tmp/(example)/script')
  #=> true
  ```
- Escaped directory as the second argument. Failure.

  ```
  system('touch', '/tmp/(example)/script'.shellescape)
  #>> touch: /tmp/\(example\)/script: No such file or directory
  #=> false
  ```

It seems that `system` escapes the name of every argument but the command (first argument). That is an issue in scripts whose command has a relative path such as:

```
system("#{__dir__}/something")
```

1. Why does `system` behave this way?
2. Is there a native option to make it escape everything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Blindly sending a whole command through `#shellescape` rarely does the right thing. Consider this:

```
> puts '(pancakes) --house'.shellescape
\(pancakes\)\ --house
```

Sure, you probably want to escape the parentheses but you almost certainly don't want to escape the space. In order to do The Right Thing and DWIM (Do What I Mean), `#system` would have to make guesses about which parts should be escaped and which parts shouldn't and it would invariably do the wrong thing half the time.

The solution is to never ever use the single argument form of `#system` so that you never invoke a shell at all. If you say things like:

```
system('/bin/ls -l')
```

then a shell is invoked with that command line and the shell has to parse it before invoking the command. If you intend say:

```
system('/bin/ls', '-l')
```

then `/bin/ls` is invoked directly, no shell is involved so there's no escaping to worry about. Of course, that sometimes leads to silly things like:

```
system('/bin/ls', '--')
system(['/bin/ls', '--'])
```

invoke a command without arguments and without a shell but presumably that's not very common and you can fall back on manual escaping when you know that's what you're dealing with.

I tend to pretend that `#system` doesn't exist and go straight to [`Open3`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.4.2/libdoc/open3/rdoc/Open3.html) when I need to interact with external programs. `Open3` is slightly more verbose but has a cleaner and easier to use interface IMO.

Similar arguments apply to using backticks to execute a command and capture its output.

---

Your second example:

```
# Unescaped directory as second argument. Success.
> system('touch', '/tmp/(example)/script')
=> true
```

works because no shell is invoked so the parentheses in the second argument have no special meaning.

Your third example:

```
# Escaped directory as second argument. Failure.
> system('touch', '/tmp/(example)/script'.shellescape)
touch: /tmp/\(example\)/script: No such file or directory
=> false
```

fails for the same reason: no shell means no escaping.

Comment: “I tend to pretend that `#system` doesn't exist and go straight to [`Open3`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.4.2/libdoc/open3/rdoc/Open3.html) (…)”. `Open3` behaves the same in this situation. I tend to use `system` when I want the command to run but don’t care about output, and `Open3` in every other case.